# Unable to import Pymongo into AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymongo

How can I use pymongo in a lambda function?

After following the instructions from AWS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-dependencies, I've found that the **pymongo** library is **not recognized by my lambda handler function**, but other local packages are.

The **python-dateutil** is a local package that **works as expected** , however the pymongo package is not recognized as an import and fails when run.

My file name is correctly listed in the lambda handler function as well (hotel-car-rental.lambda_handler) and other local package imports work fine.  So I believe it is something to do with pymongo?  How can I get pymongo to work with aws lambda?

**Here is the lambda file structure:**

- BookTrip

  - dateutil
  - pymongo
  - hotel-car-rental.py

**Here is the code:**

```
import json
import datetime
import dateutil.parser  # <--- Works with local package
import logging

from pymongo import MongoClient   # <--- Does NOT work with local package

# --- Main handler ---

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    Route the incoming request based on intent.
    The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
    """

    logger.debug('event.bot.name={}'.format(event['bot']['name']))

    return dispatch(event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this issue was by packaging up the entire 'site-packages' directory in my virtual environment, rather than just the individual package locations.  It appears pymongo installs additional dependencies, such as bson library, that are required.

Here is the specific process I used to package installed libraries for use in aws lambda.

```
mkdir -p ./package/tmp/lib
cp -a ./lambda/. ./package/tmp/
cp -a venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/. ./package/tmp/
rm -rf ./package/tmp/wheel* && rm -rf ./package/tmp/pip*
cd ./package/tmp && zip -r ../../hotel-car-rental.zip .
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also - instead of doing this since it requires copying/tinkering with your own stuff - run this inside a docker container to package up lambda.

```
docker run -v <code directory>:/function -it --rm ubuntu
apt-get update
apt-get install python-pip
apt-get install zip

cd function
pip install -t . pymongo
cd ..
zip -r linux-lambda.zip working
```

The only reason I do this now is that when using a Mac - which I do - it can sometimes give an "Invalid ELF Header" error and Lambda won't compile!

Answer (score 0):

I'm building AWS lambdas via the Serverless framework and had a similar problem. However, I've found an [official](https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-python-rest-api-with-pymongo/) [example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-python-rest-api-with-pymongo) and noticed that they provide a specific plugin for that called `serverless-python-requirements`. Once I've added it to serverless.yml

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

I've got a warning (on `serverless deploy`) that I have to install the plugin, which is done via

```
serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
```

Once I've done that, import from `pymongo` no longer causes the problem.
(also I had to add `node_modules/` to `.gitignore` and add package files to git)

---

Note: there's also a [known problem](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues/442) that some users including those using Windows + VS Code/Powershell may face with `serverless-python-requirements`: if one creates `requirements.txt` via

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

that may result in wrong encoding and `serverless deploy` fails in that case. Changing encoding to UTF-8 fixes the issue. They suggest that using

```
pip freeze | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 requirements.txt
```

instead allows to avoid this problem.